# Manipular formato de data com PHP

Tags: php, html

*Já procurei em outros tópicos e não consegui resolver.
Tenho um formulário tipo *text* que recebe datas, o usuário escreve no formato **dd/mm/aaaa**, mas quando vou debugar o valor retorna em **aaaa/mm/dd**. Preciso receber o valor no formato **dd/mm/aaaa**, já tentei vários códigos daqui mas não consegui.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="example-date-input" class="form-control-label">Nascimento do PET (dd/mm/aaaa)</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dataaniversario" id="example-date-input" maxlength="10" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem que tratar no PHP ao receber ou então no Javascript antes de enviar. `<input type="date">` exibe a data de acordo com o local do OS, mas armazena o dado em formato ISO. Outra coisa `<input type="date">` não é compatível como todos o browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No INPUT TYPE=DATE não é possível, o que você pode fazer é usar algum datepicker em JQUERY ou JS, no PHP é possivel quando você recebe o valor, converte-lo com strtodate()

Comment: Obrigado! Utilizei o strtodate e resolveu